# I am not able to get the connection string for db file

Tags: java, javafx, native

I have sqlite DB file. which i want to embed in to my native .exe or executable jar. I am not able to get the connection string for db file.

Code in sqlite.properties

```
sqlite.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
sqlite.url=jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/sqliteConfig/lic.db
```

From MyBeanFactory expecting Datasource instance.

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:sqliteConfig/sqlite.properties")
public class MyBeanFactory {
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("sqlite.driver"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("sqlite.url"));
      return dataSource;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the connection string? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: put some of your code how your are trying this.

Comment: Please verify the question again @user2408578

Comment: It work fine if am running from eclipse but when trying after creating executable jar its gives an error of connection string.

Comment: "src/main/resources" in the connection string is *strange*

Comment: @RC. I have placed by Sqlite DB file over there in src/main/resources/sqliteConfig folder as i have created project in maven

Comment: @AdityaShah unzip you jar and look for "src/main/resources", you will understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sqlite-jdbc` can open resources on its own. Per this thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xerial/Oayzj5nrJGk), add `:resource` to the path. So try the following in your `sqlite.properties` file:

```
sqlite.url=jdbc:sqlite::resource:package/test.db
```

Replacing package with the '/' separated path to the package this file is in.

Comment: thank you for your kind support. It really worked out.